# Calculating Lipschitz constant of the gradient of $\sqrt {1+(x-2y-1)^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate the Lipschitz constant of the gradient of $f(x,y)=\sqrt {1+(x-2y-1)^2}$?

Just using the definition of the constant did not work. Can I perform a manipulation on the function that will ease the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
\nabla f = \frac{(x-2y-1)\mathbf{i}-2(x-2y-1)\mathbf{j}}{\sqrt{1+(x-2y-1)^2}}
\end{align}
then it suffices to study the function
\begin{align}
g(x, y) = \frac{x-2y-1}{\sqrt{1+(x-2y-1)^2}}.
\end{align}
Observe we have
\begin{align}
\nabla g = \frac{\mathbf{i}-2\mathbf{j}}{(1+(x-2y-1)^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\|\nabla g\| \leq \sqrt{5}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\|\nabla f(a, b) - \nabla f(c, d)\| = \sqrt{5}|g(a, b)-g(c, d)| \leq 5 \|  (a-c, b-d)\|.
\end{align}

Comment: With this approach shouldn't we demand that $||\text {Hessian}(f)||$ is bounded? I'm trying to calculate the Lipschitz constant of the gradient and not the constant of the function. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MasterJ My mistake. I misread the question.